# Laravel Route Composer restful with no name

Tags: rest, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use the laravel route composer but I want it to have no name. What I mean is instead of doing /user/{id} or /user/{id}/show, I just want to have is so it's /{id} and /{id}/show like that.

Also what about having one inside it so like status, i.e.

/{id}/status/{id}/show

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:** Try

```
Route::resource('/', 'UserController');
Route::resource('/.status', 'UserStatusController');
```

It will give you

```
+----------------------------------+----------------+------------------------------+
| URI                              | Name           | Action                       |
+----------------------------------+----------------+------------------------------+
| GET|HEAD /                       | index          | UserController@index         |
| GET|HEAD create                  | create         | UserController@create        |
| POST /                           | store          | UserController@store         |
| GET|HEAD {}                      | show           | UserController@show          |
| GET|HEAD {}/edit                 | edit           | UserController@edit          |
| PUT {}                           | update         | UserController@update        |
| PATCH {}                         |                | UserController@update        |
| DELETE {}                        | destroy        | UserController@destroy       |
| GET|HEAD {}/status               | status.index   | UserStatusController@index   |
| GET|HEAD {}/status/create        | status.create  | UserStatusController@create  |
| POST {}/status                   | status.store   | UserStatusController@store   |
| GET|HEAD {}/status/{status}      | status.show    | UserStatusController@show    |
| GET|HEAD {}/status/{status}/edit | status.edit    | UserStatusController@edit    |
| PUT {}/status/{status}           | status.update  | UserStatusController@update  |
| PATCH {}/status/{status}         |                | UserStatusController@update  |
| DELETE {}/status/{status}        | status.destroy | UserStatusController@destroy |
+----------------------------------+----------------+------------------------------+
```

In your `UserStatusController`

```
class UserStatusController extends BaseController
{
    public function edit($user_id, $status_id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

See [Handling Nested Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: that doesn't work. you'll get an error if you try and access the actual links.

Comment: @ShemsEddine It doesn't work because you're doing something wrong. Post relevant parts of your code and the error message if you want to be helped.